# How to retain ASP.Net validation summary on Postback

Tags: asp.net, validation, postback, validationsummary

I have a aspx page with multiple groups to be validated. validation on groups happen based on some conditions I have written.

Currently all my validation work fine with client side validation.

But, when I do a postback the validation summary is getting disappeared. In the post back I am enabling some additional controls which are not yet touched by the user( so validation should not happen on this newly visible controls).

so My problems are:

1. To Retain the Validation summary generated by client side script on post back.
2. Only Validation messages that are generated on client side should be visible.
3. Newly added field should not be validated on postback(fields that are untouched).

Please suggest....

Answer (score 0):

In the post back event handler add the invalid validators by calling

```
Page.Validate("Group");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To Retain the Validation summary generated by client side script on post back.

I think you should check ViewState.EnablViewState=true

1. Newly added field should not be validated on postback(fields that are untouched).
   Use ValidationGroup.Apply different ValidationGroup for different input and related button.
2. Only Validation messages that are generated on client side should be visible.
   Not fully understood.May be by solving 1 & 3 this will disappear .